# Trying to Linux desktop using VNC, getting a different screen

Tags: linux, vnc, vncserver

I have a SUSE desktop Linux system running. Now when I am trying to vnc into that system from a VNC client (from a Windows XP box), all I get is a blank desktop with a XTerm running on it. My SUSE desktop had loads of apps and terminals running -- can't see any of them. Any idea what might be going wrong here?

I had earlier invoked vncserver on my SUSE desktop as "vncserver" and no options. Maybe I need additional options to make the desktop visible? Or maybe tweak vnc script or xinitrc files, not sure.

Comment: "I had earlier invoked vncserver" and it worked then?

Comment: Are you using multiple screens on your Linux desktop?  If so, then perhaps your VNC client is only showing one of them?  _(I assume you know that the desktop background image, a.k.a. "wallpaper," is often temporarily removed to make the sessions work more efficiently.)_

Comment: @soandos -- I was merely mentioning how I invoked vncserver.

Comment: @Randolf -- The issue is not with wallpaper being removed, although I am indeed using multiple screens. I don't even see the start panel or any other terminals etc.

Answer (score 1):

Most VNC servers create a new X session and share that.  If you want to share your current X session, you have a couple options:

If you're using KDE, use [KDE Desktop Sharing, a.k.a. `krfb`](http://www.kde.org/applications/system/krfb/).  It's included in most default KDE installations, but I can't speak for SUSE.  If it's not installed, you can install it by locating it in YaST or from a terminal by running:

```
zypper install krfb
```

Once installed, just run *Desktop Sharing* from the Internet menu in Kicker, or by running `krfb` in KRunner or a terminal.  I suggest you set *Allow uninvited connections* and configure a password in its configuration to prevent having to deal with the invitation system intended for allowing other users to share your desktop.

If you're using GNOME, use `vino` instead.  It's available in the openSUSE repositories so I imagine SUSE Linux Enterprise has it too.  Install it from YaST or run:

```
zypper install vino
```

Once installed, you can find it on the *Preferences* submenu of your *System* menu.

Comment: +1. Using vino is definitely a step in the right direction for me. However, the data sent is un-encrypted. Any thoughts? Also is vino resource hungry like krfb is known to be? What processes run on the server side for vino?

Comment: @Fanatic23:  `vino` has it's own VNC server, `vino-server`.  I have no idea how performant it is.  (I don't use it, or GNOME for that matter.)  Supposedly it supports VNC's (admittedly poor) built-in encryption with just a check box in the configuration. You could also use SSH or `stunnel`.